# MySQL select with blob increase performance

Tags: mysql

This `sql select` is too slow with a lot of data, how can I increase it's run speed in `mysql`?

```
SELECT c.car_id, o.start_date, own.name 
FROM Cars c
JOIN Orders o ON c.car_id = o.car_id 
JOIN Owner own ON o.order_id = own.owner_id 
WHERE c.wheel IS NOT NULL AND c.document IS NULL ORDER BY c.car_id DESC;
```

the document field is a blob.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what takes how long

Comment: please define what "too slow" and "a lot of data" means.

Comment: Like @PawełŁukasik said, [edit] your post to give us enough information to help you with a performance problem. Read this, especially the part on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: Make sure that fields are used to join table and for where conditions have index created.